# asyns function in pywebio

Tags: python

```
import asyncio

from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import run_async

max_message_count = 3
messages = []

async def updateMSG(name, msg_box):
    global messages
    last_len = 0

    while True:
        lenth = len(messages)
        if last_len != lenth:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"`{name}`: {messages[len(messages)-1]}"))
            last_len = len(messages)

async def main():
    global messages

    name = await input("Name: ")
    put_markdown(f"Добро пожаловать, {name}!")

    msg_box = output()
    put_scrollable(msg_box, height=300, keep_bottom=True)
    run_async(updateMSG(name, msg_box))
    messages.append(f"Добро пожаловать, {name}!")

    while True:
        msg = await input(placeholder="Текст сообщения ...")
        messages.append(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server(main, debug=True, port=8080, cdn=False)
```

На начальном экране, где нужно ввести имя, всё работает нормально. Но там, где нужно вводить сообщения - нет. Она просто становится невидимой.

Конкретно тут

```
while True:
        msg = await input(placeholder="Текст сообщения ...")
        messages.append(msg)
```

После кнопки "Отправить" всё зависает и становится некликабельным

Делал 2 асинхронные функции, но это не помогло. Запускалась только одна...

```
run_async(updateMSG(name, msg_box))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeBot.png)

Comment: The message update function works well. The problem is entering the message.